# How to retrieve Campaign Member Status picklist availability for Lead Record Types?

Tags: picklist, record-type, leads, campaign, campaign-member

When you go to the Lead Record Type section you can see the Campaign Member Status picklist even if that field is not on the Lead itself but on the Campaign Member (that can be a Lead or a Contact). Now I'm trying to retrieve picklist value availability for the two Record Types that I have on the Lead but I'm not able to retrieve that picklist configuration with the Record Type (all fields are mentioned in the Record Type metadata, except for that one).
The retrieve is made via package, including the CustomObject "Lead" and the target RecordType.
I also tried to include the StandardValueSet "CampaignMemberStatus" to check if this affect the RecordType metadata, but it doesn't.

Comment: @https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox do you have any tip for this? :)